# Can't import pygame in sublime text on m1 mac

Tags: python, macos, pygame, sublimetext, apple-m1

I'm trying to install pygame to use on my m1 mac.
I'm trying to just test import the module: import pygame, but keep getting errors.

I found out pygame is installed for python 3, so i switched the build mode to python 3 in sublime text. I keep getting this error:

```
  File "/Users/username/Documents/python_projects/games/test/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from pygame.base import * # pylint: disable=wildcard-import; lgtm[py/polluting-import]
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _SDL_DestroyWindow
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-39-darwin.so
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['python3', '-u', '/Users/username/Documents/python_projects/games/test/test.py']]
[dir: /Users/username/Documents/python_projects/games/test]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you need to install SDL

download [here](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php)

get the "`Mac OS X`" `"SDL2-2.0.16.dmg"`runtime

Comment: Hey thanks.
I downloaded and installed that and unfortunately I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @TomRodwell Is SDL listed in your system path?

Comment: When I print sys.path, I can't see SDL in there.
How do I get it in there ?

Comment: you need to have SDL added to the system path. [try this](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation)

Comment: I'm having trouble following along with the mac os part of that guide.
I'm not sure what ```CC=/where/i/cloned/SDL/build-scripts/clang-fat.sh ../configure``` is meant to be, I don't have any clang-fat.sh file in mine.

Comment: Pygame wheels come with SDL and all of its other C dependencies. If you’re trying to compile from source, which ain’t a bad idea, since there aren’t wheels for M1 Mac, you can use brew to install deps. See https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile

Comment: Thanks for this. I followed the steps in your link and everything was successful but I'm still getting the same error in sublime text